# when two features are equally correlated with the target variable which one to choose

Tags: statistics, data-science

Say for example I have two continuous/quantitative predictor features f1, f2, and a target continuous variable t. Pearson correlation of f1 vs t is 0.7 & f2 vs t is also 0.7

Now I have to make a decision to keep only one out of 2 predictor features. Which other statistical tests I can perform that will help me to make this decision?

I want to make this decision without using any of lasso, ridge or PCA. But purely using statistical tests
. Which are the best NHST if any that can help here?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can compare the [Spearman's Rank Correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) of each predictor to the target variable. Also, we can convert the predictors and target from continuous to ordinal features (e.g. by [binning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_binning)) and try [ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance) or [Kendall's Tau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient).

You might find [this article](https://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-selection-with-real-and-categorical-data/) useful.